# SQL query result multiplied and brings up wrong result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, left-join

I have the following query that brings up quantities for certain items from certain locations.

```
SELECT l.region, l.Region_Description, s.store_code AS store, s.name, s.city, p.province_code, s.telephone,  b.store_code, b.product_code,  b.product_id,  
COALESCE(SUM(CONVERT(INT, b.bin_qty_stocks)),0) AS inv
,  dbo.pp_fnGetHoldbackQuantity(c.Channel_Index - 1, b.product_id) AS web_hb
,  CASE WHEN b.store_code = '0010' THEN SUM(CONVERT(INT, b.bin_qty_stocks))  - dbo.pp_fnGetHoldbackQuantity(c.Channel_Index - 1, b.product_id) 
    ELSE COALESCE(SUM(CONVERT(INT, b.bin_qty_stocks)),0)  END AS inv_avail
, (SELECT SKU FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 1) AS Alt1SKU
, COALESCE(SUM(CONVERT(INT, Alt1.bin_qty_stocks)),0) AS Alt1Qty
, (SELECT SKU FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 2) AS Alt2SKU
, COALESCE(SUM(CONVERT(INT, Alt2.bin_qty_stocks)),0) AS Alt2Qty
, (SELECT SKU FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 3) AS Alt3SKU
, COALESCE(SUM(CONVERT(INT, Alt3.bin_qty_stocks)),0) AS Alt3Qty
, (SELECT SKU FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 4) AS Alt4SKU
, COALESCE(SUM(CONVERT(INT, Alt4.bin_qty_stocks)),0) AS Alt4Qty
, (SELECT SKU FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 5) AS Alt5SKU
, COALESCE(SUM(CONVERT(INT, Alt5.bin_qty_stocks)),0) AS Alt5Qty
, (SELECT SKU FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 6) AS Alt6SKU
, COALESCE(SUM(CONVERT(INT, Alt6.bin_qty_stocks)),0) AS Alt6Qty
, (SELECT RegularPrice FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 1) AS Alt1Price
, (SELECT RegularPrice FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 2) AS Alt2Price
, (SELECT RegularPrice FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 3) AS Alt3Price
, (SELECT RegularPrice FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 4) AS Alt4Price
, (SELECT RegularPrice FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 5) AS Alt5Price
, (SELECT RegularPrice FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 6) AS Alt6Price
, (SELECT POSDescription FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 1) AS Alt1Desc
, (SELECT POSDescription FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 2) AS Alt2Desc
, (SELECT POSDescription FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 3) AS Alt3Desc
, (SELECT POSDescription FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 4) AS Alt4Desc
, (SELECT POSDescription FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 5) AS Alt5Desc
, (SELECT POSDescription FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 6) AS Alt6Desc
FROM store s 
    INNER JOIN province p
        ON p.province_id = s.province_id
    INNER JOIN pp_vStoreLevels l  
        ON l.store_code_id = s.store_Code_id
    LEFT JOIN pp_BUCKET b 
        ON b.store_code_id = s.store_code_id
        AND b.Bin_Code in ('STORE', 'VW', 'V') 
        AND b.product_code = @inSKU
    LEFT JOIN @BUCKET Alt1 
        ON Alt1.store_code_id = s.store_code_id
        AND Alt1.Bin_Code in ('STORE', 'VW', 'V')
        AND Alt1.product_code in (SELECT SKU FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 1)
    LEFT JOIN @BUCKET Alt2 
        ON Alt2.store_code_id = s.store_code_id
        AND Alt2.Bin_Code in ('STORE', 'VW', 'V') 
        AND Alt2.product_code in (SELECT SKU FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 2)
    LEFT JOIN @BUCKET Alt3 
        ON Alt3.store_code_id = s.store_code_id
        AND Alt3.Bin_Code in ('STORE', 'VW', 'V') 
        AND Alt3.product_code in (SELECT SKU FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 3)
    LEFT JOIN @BUCKET Alt4 
        ON Alt4.store_code_id = s.store_code_id
        AND Alt4.Bin_Code in ('STORE', 'VW', 'V') 
        AND Alt4.product_code in (SELECT SKU FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 4)
    LEFT JOIN @BUCKET Alt5 
        ON Alt5.store_code_id = s.store_code_id
        AND Alt5.Bin_Code in ('STORE', 'VW', 'V') 
        AND Alt5.product_code in (SELECT SKU FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 5)
    LEFT JOIN @BUCKET Alt6 
        ON Alt6.store_code_id = s.store_code_id
        AND Alt6.Bin_Code in ('STORE', 'VW', 'V') 
        AND Alt6.product_code in (SELECT SKU FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 6)
    CROSS JOIN pp_Channel c             
WHERE (((l.region IS NOT NULL) AND (l.region <> '099')) OR (l.store = '0010'))
    AND s.store_code <> '0012'
    AND (l.date_opened <= GETDATE())
    AND ((l.date_closed IS NULL) OR (l.date_closed > GETDATE()))    
    AND c.channel_description = 'TEST'  
GROUP BY l.region, l.region_description, s.store_code, s.name, s.city, p.province_code, s.telephone
, b.store_code, b.product_code, b.product_id, c.Channel_Index
```

Before this query, I'm building two temp tables @ALT and @BUCKET. In @ALT, I'm storing alternate item codes for the supplied item @inSKU. in @BUCKET, I'm storing inventory quantities for all items that are in @ALT.

The issue is, I'm getting a multiplied quantity in "inv". If there are 4 alternate items, the inv quantity is multiplied by 4. I don't see why this is happening, which is why I'm asking for some help identifying this issue. If I comment out the Alt1Qty, Alt2Qty, Alt3Qty, Alt4Qty, Alt5Qty, Alt6Qty joins, I get the correct result.

Please advise.

Thanks.

Update: There are really two sections that need to be looked at
Section 1:

```
COALESCE(SUM(CONVERT(INT, b.bin_qty_stocks)),0) AS inv
,  dbo.pp_fnGetHoldbackQuantity(c.Channel_Index - 1, b.product_id) AS web_hb
,  CASE WHEN b.store_code = '0010' THEN SUM(CONVERT(INT, b.bin_qty_stocks))  - dbo.pp_fnGetHoldbackQuantity(c.Channel_Index - 1, b.product_id) 
    ELSE COALESCE(SUM(CONVERT(INT, b.bin_qty_stocks)),0)  END AS inv_avail
, COALESCE(SUM(CONVERT(INT, Alt1.bin_qty_stocks)),0) AS Alt1Qty
, COALESCE(SUM(CONVERT(INT, Alt2.bin_qty_stocks)),0) AS Alt2Qty
, COALESCE(SUM(CONVERT(INT, Alt3.bin_qty_stocks)),0) AS Alt3Qty
, COALESCE(SUM(CONVERT(INT, Alt4.bin_qty_stocks)),0) AS Alt4Qty
, COALESCE(SUM(CONVERT(INT, Alt5.bin_qty_stocks)),0) AS Alt5Qty
, COALESCE(SUM(CONVERT(INT, Alt6.bin_qty_stocks)),0) AS Alt6Qty
```

Section 2:

```
    LEFT JOIN pp_BUCKET b 
        ON b.store_code_id = s.store_code_id
        AND b.product_code = @inSKU
    LEFT JOIN @BUCKET Alt1 
        ON Alt1.store_code_id = s.store_code_id
        AND Alt1.product_code in (SELECT SKU FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 1)
    LEFT JOIN @BUCKET Alt2 
        ON Alt2.store_code_id = s.store_code_id
        AND Alt2.product_code in (SELECT SKU FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 2)
    LEFT JOIN @BUCKET Alt3 
        ON Alt3.store_code_id = s.store_code_id
        AND Alt3.product_code in (SELECT SKU FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 3)
    LEFT JOIN @BUCKET Alt4 
        ON Alt4.store_code_id = s.store_code_id
        AND Alt4.product_code in (SELECT SKU FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 4)
    LEFT JOIN @BUCKET Alt5 
        ON Alt5.store_code_id = s.store_code_id
        AND Alt5.product_code in (SELECT SKU FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 5)
    LEFT JOIN @BUCKET Alt6 
        ON Alt6.store_code_id = s.store_code_id
        AND Alt6.product_code in (SELECT SKU FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 6)
```

Comment: You must be kidding. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve!

Comment: jarlh, if you're referring to the large query, it's mostly repeats and not hard to read for the experts here.

Comment: that's really not the point.  Why should I have to work that hard to help you?  Simplify your query to help get at the root problem.  YOU need to put a little effort into your question

Comment: updated my question. I always thought that more information is better :)

Comment: do any of those left joins result in more than 1 row being joined in? (they must) which means you need to either get the inventory before the joins OR use a window function if supported to only partition by inventory in the pp_BUCKET table  perhaps: `coalesce(SUM(CONVERT(INT, case when b.Bin_Code in ('STORE', 'VW', 'V') then b.bin_qty_stocks else 0 end)),0) over (partition by b.store_Code_ID) AS inv`

Comment: xQbert, unfortunately I'm using sql 2008 and the over function isn't available. any alternate options?

Comment: @Eclipse - of course it is it was added in 2005 version.  (xQbert had a typo with the coalesce -- it needs to be inside the case.)

Comment: I am getting this : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'over'.

Comment: @Eclipse I just said... there is a typo in xQbert's line.

Comment: There is no such thing as "SQL 2008". SQL is a _query language, not a specific DBMS product. Did you mean "SQL Server 2008"?

Comment: @xQbert Would you be kind enough to elaborate a bit on your solution? I tried this and got close but there are some repeats which I need some help with. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on what you've done, one approach is to sum the inventory quantities before you join to the other tables so the inventory count's can't be inflated by the 1:M joins to other tables:

something like...  (since I don't have your tables/data this is untested)

```
SELECT l.region
     , l.Region_Description
     , s.store_code AS store
     , s.name
     , s.city
     , p.province_code
     , s.telephone
     , b.store_code
     , b.product_code
     , b.product_id
     , COALESCE(CONVERT(INT, b.sum_bin_qty_stocks),0) AS inv
     , dbo.pp_fnGetHoldbackQuantity(c.Channel_Index - 1, b.product_id) AS web_hb
     , sum(CASE WHEN b.store_code = '0010' THEN CONVERT(INT, b.sum_bin_qty_stocks)  - dbo.pp_fnGetHoldbackQuantity(c.Channel_Index - 1, b.product_id) 
             ELSE COALESCE(CONVERT(INT, b.sum_bin_qty_stocks),0)  END AS inv_avail
     , (SELECT SKU FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 1) AS Alt1SKU
     , COALESCE(SUM(CONVERT(INT, Alt1.bin_qty_stocks)),0) AS Alt1Qty
     , (SELECT SKU FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 2) AS Alt2SKU
     , COALESCE(SUM(CONVERT(INT, Alt2.bin_qty_stocks)),0) AS Alt2Qty
     , (SELECT SKU FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 3) AS Alt3SKU
     , COALESCE(SUM(CONVERT(INT, Alt3.bin_qty_stocks)),0) AS Alt3Qty
     , (SELECT SKU FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 4) AS Alt4SKU
     , COALESCE(SUM(CONVERT(INT, Alt4.bin_qty_stocks)),0) AS Alt4Qty
     , (SELECT SKU FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 5) AS Alt5SKU
     , COALESCE(SUM(CONVERT(INT, Alt5.bin_qty_stocks)),0) AS Alt5Qty
     , (SELECT SKU FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 6) AS Alt6SKU
     , COALESCE(SUM(CONVERT(INT, Alt6.bin_qty_stocks)),0) AS Alt6Qty
     , (SELECT RegularPrice FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 1) AS Alt1Price
     , (SELECT RegularPrice FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 2) AS Alt2Price
     , (SELECT RegularPrice FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 3) AS Alt3Price
     , (SELECT RegularPrice FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 4) AS Alt4Price
     , (SELECT RegularPrice FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 5) AS Alt5Price
     , (SELECT RegularPrice FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 6) AS Alt6Price
     , (SELECT POSDescription FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 1) AS Alt1Desc
     , (SELECT POSDescription FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 2) AS Alt2Desc
     , (SELECT POSDescription FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 3) AS Alt3Desc
     , (SELECT POSDescription FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 4) AS Alt4Desc
     , (SELECT POSDescription FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 5) AS Alt5Desc
     , (SELECT POSDescription FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 6) AS Alt6Desc
FROM store s 
    INNER JOIN province p
        ON p.province_id = s.province_id
    INNER JOIN pp_vStoreLevels l  
        ON l.store_code_id = s.store_Code_id
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT sum(bin_qty_Stocks) as Sum_bin_Qty_Stocks, store_Code_Id, store_code, product_code, product_id
               FROM pp_BUCKET b 
               WHERE Bin_Code in ('STORE', 'VW', 'V') 
                 AND product_code = @inSKU
               GROUP BY store_Code_Id, store_code, product_code, product_id) b
        ON b.store_code_id = s.store_code_id
    LEFT JOIN @BUCKET Alt1 
        ON Alt1.store_code_id = s.store_code_id
        AND Alt1.Bin_Code in ('STORE', 'VW', 'V')
        AND Alt1.product_code in (SELECT SKU FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 1)
    LEFT JOIN @BUCKET Alt2 
        ON Alt2.store_code_id = s.store_code_id
        AND Alt2.Bin_Code in ('STORE', 'VW', 'V') 
        AND Alt2.product_code in (SELECT SKU FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 2)
    LEFT JOIN @BUCKET Alt3 
        ON Alt3.store_code_id = s.store_code_id
        AND Alt3.Bin_Code in ('STORE', 'VW', 'V') 
        AND Alt3.product_code in (SELECT SKU FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 3)
    LEFT JOIN @BUCKET Alt4 
        ON Alt4.store_code_id = s.store_code_id
        AND Alt4.Bin_Code in ('STORE', 'VW', 'V') 
        AND Alt4.product_code in (SELECT SKU FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 4)
    LEFT JOIN @BUCKET Alt5 
        ON Alt5.store_code_id = s.store_code_id
        AND Alt5.Bin_Code in ('STORE', 'VW', 'V') 
        AND Alt5.product_code in (SELECT SKU FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 5)
    LEFT JOIN @BUCKET Alt6 
        ON Alt6.store_code_id = s.store_code_id
        AND Alt6.Bin_Code in ('STORE', 'VW', 'V') 
        AND Alt6.product_code in (SELECT SKU FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 6)
    CROSS JOIN pp_Channel c             
WHERE (((l.region IS NOT NULL) AND (l.region <> '099')) OR (l.store = '0010'))
    AND s.store_code <> '0012'
    AND (l.date_opened <= GETDATE())
    AND ((l.date_closed IS NULL) OR (l.date_closed > GETDATE()))    
    AND c.channel_description = 'TEST'  
GROUP BY l.region, l.region_description, s.store_code, s.name, s.city, p.province_code, s.telephone
, b.store_code, b.product_code, b.product_id, c.Channel_Index
```

Maybe using a window function (again untested)  but I think I'd have to work a case in there to handle conditional sum based on    `AND b.Bin_Code in ('STORE', 'VW', 'V') 
        AND b.product_code = @inSKU`  So I think the first approach is cleaner.

```
SELECT l.region
     , l.Region_Description
     , s.store_code AS store
     , s.name
     , s.city
     , p.province_code
     , s.telephone
     , b.store_code
     , b.product_code
     , b.product_id
     , coalesce(sum(b.vin_qty_stocks) over (partition by b.store_code, b.product_code, b.product_id),0) as INV
     , dbo.pp_fnGetHoldbackQuantity(c.Channel_Index - 1, b.product_id) AS web_hb
     , sum(CASE WHEN b.store_code = '0010' THEN coalesce(sum(b.vin_qty_stocks) over (partition by b.store_code, b.product_code, b.product_id),0) - dbo.pp_fnGetHoldbackQuantity(c.Channel_Index - 1, b.product_id) 
             ELSE coalesce(sum(b.vin_qty_stocks) over (partition by b.store_code, b.product_code, b.product_id),0)  END AS inv_avail
     , (SELECT SKU FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 1) AS Alt1SKU
     , COALESCE(SUM(CONVERT(INT, Alt1.bin_qty_stocks)),0) AS Alt1Qty
     , (SELECT SKU FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 2) AS Alt2SKU
     , COALESCE(SUM(CONVERT(INT, Alt2.bin_qty_stocks)),0) AS Alt2Qty
     , (SELECT SKU FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 3) AS Alt3SKU
     , COALESCE(SUM(CONVERT(INT, Alt3.bin_qty_stocks)),0) AS Alt3Qty
     , (SELECT SKU FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 4) AS Alt4SKU
     , COALESCE(SUM(CONVERT(INT, Alt4.bin_qty_stocks)),0) AS Alt4Qty
     , (SELECT SKU FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 5) AS Alt5SKU
     , COALESCE(SUM(CONVERT(INT, Alt5.bin_qty_stocks)),0) AS Alt5Qty
     , (SELECT SKU FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 6) AS Alt6SKU
     , COALESCE(SUM(CONVERT(INT, Alt6.bin_qty_stocks)),0) AS Alt6Qty
     , (SELECT RegularPrice FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 1) AS Alt1Price
     , (SELECT RegularPrice FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 2) AS Alt2Price
     , (SELECT RegularPrice FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 3) AS Alt3Price
     , (SELECT RegularPrice FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 4) AS Alt4Price
     , (SELECT RegularPrice FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 5) AS Alt5Price
     , (SELECT RegularPrice FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 6) AS Alt6Price
     , (SELECT POSDescription FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 1) AS Alt1Desc
     , (SELECT POSDescription FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 2) AS Alt2Desc
     , (SELECT POSDescription FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 3) AS Alt3Desc
     , (SELECT POSDescription FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 4) AS Alt4Desc
     , (SELECT POSDescription FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 5) AS Alt5Desc
     , (SELECT POSDescription FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 6) AS Alt6Desc
FROM store s 
    INNER JOIN province p
        ON p.province_id = s.province_id
    INNER JOIN pp_vStoreLevels l  
        ON l.store_code_id = s.store_Code_id
    LEFT JOIN pp_BUCKET b 
        ON b.store_code_id = s.store_code_id
        AND b.Bin_Code in ('STORE', 'VW', 'V') 
        AND b.product_code = @inSKU
    LEFT JOIN @BUCKET Alt1 
        ON Alt1.store_code_id = s.store_code_id
        AND Alt1.Bin_Code in ('STORE', 'VW', 'V')
        AND Alt1.product_code in (SELECT SKU FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 1)
    LEFT JOIN @BUCKET Alt2 
        ON Alt2.store_code_id = s.store_code_id
        AND Alt2.Bin_Code in ('STORE', 'VW', 'V') 
        AND Alt2.product_code in (SELECT SKU FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 2)
    LEFT JOIN @BUCKET Alt3 
        ON Alt3.store_code_id = s.store_code_id
        AND Alt3.Bin_Code in ('STORE', 'VW', 'V') 
        AND Alt3.product_code in (SELECT SKU FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 3)
    LEFT JOIN @BUCKET Alt4 
        ON Alt4.store_code_id = s.store_code_id
        AND Alt4.Bin_Code in ('STORE', 'VW', 'V') 
        AND Alt4.product_code in (SELECT SKU FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 4)
    LEFT JOIN @BUCKET Alt5 
        ON Alt5.store_code_id = s.store_code_id
        AND Alt5.Bin_Code in ('STORE', 'VW', 'V') 
        AND Alt5.product_code in (SELECT SKU FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 5)
    LEFT JOIN @BUCKET Alt6 
        ON Alt6.store_code_id = s.store_code_id
        AND Alt6.Bin_Code in ('STORE', 'VW', 'V') 
        AND Alt6.product_code in (SELECT SKU FROM @ALT WHERE RN = 6)
    CROSS JOIN pp_Channel c             
WHERE (((l.region IS NOT NULL) AND (l.region <> '099')) OR (l.store = '0010'))
    AND s.store_code <> '0012'
    AND (l.date_opened <= GETDATE())
    AND ((l.date_closed IS NULL) OR (l.date_closed > GETDATE()))    
    AND c.channel_description = 'TEST'  
GROUP BY l.region, l.region_description, s.store_code, s.name, s.city, p.province_code, s.telephone
, b.store_code, b.product_code, b.product_id, c.Channel_Index
```

Now both of these are based on an assumption that one or more of the alts have more than 1 record being generated if you instead generated the "Sum totals" inside the @bucket tables or as sub queries so that only 1 record resulted for each store_Code_ID then this you don't need either of the above as you've fixed the root of the problem.

Comment: you nailed it. I tried the first method and with a little tweak, I have the correct sum. I will continue the test with some more sample data to make sure the numbers are correct. I wish there are more people like you here and everywhere. Thanks so much.

Comment: We aim to please.  It's a matter of being around long enough to have seen most of the problems once and knowing how to fix them when they arise again.  Hope it works out.

Comment: I still have an issue. Seems like the first quantity for primary sku is fixes but for the alt ones, it's still multiplying for a specific store. Could you please look at my full code here http://pastebin.com/erJyjB2z so you know what I'm trying to do? Thanks.

Comment: It works if I remove the SUM from these statements...  
 , COALESCE(CONVERT(INT, sib1.bin_qty_stocks),0) AS Sib1Qty
 , (SELECT SKU FROM @SIBS WHERE RN = 2) AS Sib2SKU
 , COALESCE(CONVERT(INT, sib2.bin_qty_stocks),0) AS Sib2Qty
but if I do this, I'm not sure I'm always getting the right result. Also, I would need to add every one of these (sib1.bin_qty_stocks) iteration in the group by clause

Comment: please let me know if you have any suggestions to improve this. Thanks.

Comment: The only way I can think of is to generate subselects for the Alts as well, thereby eliminating the need to sum in the outer query.  Similar to what we did for pp_BUCKET.  I don't have the time today to really look into it.  but my guess is the multiple records from each of the alts is causing the issue to eliminate that problem you need 1 record per storeID for each alt, which could be resolved using subqueries, or when you generate the @bucket table, sum by store on creation.

Comment: I've modified the code to do the sum prior when I insert data into `@BUCKET or @VBIN` then removed all the SUM from the final select. please see here http://pastebin.com/UivUEiKe and let me know if this would work. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem (which we can't solve for sure just viewing this sql) will become clear to you if we re-write the SQL so it is sane.  Below you will find sql that is functionally the same as the SQL you posted.

So what do we see?   Well altStuff is a strange construct but it might be what you want to do.  It won't work if there is more than one row -- so first check that -- run that sub query and see if it just gives you one row.  If  it doesn't (which I'd stake a dinner on) then that is your problem -- you should fix it.

> Note: this is the same problem that xQbert was going to fix with the OVER clause in the comments, but in this case it is clearer because I've broken it using a `with` clause.

If it isn't in altStuff then pp_channel is probably the problem if it has 4 rows.   Failing that, I've no idea what the problem is.

```
WITH altStuff AS
(
  SELECT 
    Alt1.SKU AS Alt1SKU,
    Alt2.SKU AS Alt2SKU, 
    Alt3.SKU AS Alt3SKU,
    Alt4.SKU AS Alt4SKU, 
    Alt5.SKU AS Alt5SKU, 
    Alt6.SKU AS Alt6SKU, 
    ALT1.RegularPrice AS Alt1Price, 
    ALT2.RegularPrice AS Alt2Price,
    ALT3.RegularPrice AS Alt3Price,
    ALT4.RegularPrice AS Alt4Price, 
    ALT5.RegularPrice AS Alt5Price, 
    ALT6.RegularPrice AS Alt6Price, 
    ALT1.POSDescription AS Alt1Desc,
    ALT2.POSDescription AS Alt2Desc, 
    ALT3.POSDescription AS Alt3Desc,
    ALT4.POSDescription AS Alt4Desc,
    ALT5.POSDescription AS Alt5Desc,
    ALT6.POSDescription AS Alt6Desc,
    COALESCE(SUM(CONVERT(INT, Alt1.bin_qty_stocks)),0) AS Alt1Qty,
    COALESCE(SUM(CONVERT(INT, Alt2.bin_qty_stocks)),0) AS Alt2Qty, 
    COALESCE(SUM(CONVERT(INT, Alt3.bin_qty_stocks)),0) AS Alt3Qty,
    COALESCE(SUM(CONVERT(INT, Alt4.bin_qty_stocks)),0) AS Alt4Qty,
    COALESCE(SUM(CONVERT(INT, Alt5.bin_qty_stocks)),0) AS Alt5Qty,
    COALESCE(SUM(CONVERT(INT, Alt6.bin_qty_stocks)),0) AS Alt6Qty,
  FROM @ALT ALT1
  CROSS JOIN @ALT ALT2 
  CROSS JOIN @ALT ALT3 
  CROSS JOIN @ALT ALT4 
  CROSS JOIN @ALT ALT5 
  CROSS JOIN @ALT ALT6 
  WHERE ALT1.RN = 1 AND ALT2.RN = 2 AND ALT3.RN = 3 AND ALT4.RN = 4 AND ALT5.RN = 5 AND ALT6.RN = 6
)
SELECT l.region, l.Region_Description, s.store_code AS store, s.name, s.city, p.province_code, s.telephone,  b.store_code, b.product_code,  b.product_id,  
  COALESCE(SUM(CONVERT(INT, b.bin_qty_stocks)),0) AS inv,
  dbo.pp_fnGetHoldbackQuantity(c.Channel_Index - 1, b.product_id) AS web_hb,
  CASE WHEN b.store_code = '0010' 
       THEN SUM(CONVERT(INT, b.bin_qty_stocks))  - dbo.pp_fnGetHoldbackQuantity(c.Channel_Index - 1, b.product_id) 
       ELSE COALESCE(SUM(CONVERT(INT, b.bin_qty_stocks)),0)
  END AS inv_avail,
  altStuff.Alt1SKU,
  altStuff.Alt1Qty,
  altStuff.Alt2SKU, 
  altStuff.Alt2Qty, 
  altStuff.Alt3SKU,
  altStuff.Alt3Qty,
  altStuff.Alt4SKU, 
  altStuff.Alt4Qty,
  altStuff.Alt5SKU, 
  altStuff.Alt5Qty,
  altStuff.Alt6SKU, 
  altStuff.Alt6Qty,
  altStuff.Alt1Price, 
  altStuff.Alt2Price,
  altStuff.Alt3Price,
  altStuff.Alt4Price, 
  altStuff.Alt5Price, 
  altStuff.Alt6Price, 
  altStuff.Alt1Desc,
  altStuff.Alt2Desc, 
  altStuff.Alt3Desc,
  altStuff.Alt4Desc,
  altStuff.Alt5Desc,
  altStuff.Alt6Desc
FROM store s 
INNER JOIN province p ON p.province_id = s.province_id
INNER JOIN pp_vStoreLevels l ON l.store_code_id = s.store_Code_id
LEFT JOIN pp_BUCKET b ON b.store_code_id = s.store_code_id AND b.Bin_Code in ('STORE', 'VW', 'V') AND b.product_code = @inSKU
LEFT JOIN @BUCKET Alt1 ON Alt1.store_code_id = s.store_code_id AND Alt1.Bin_Code in ('STORE', 'VW', 'V') AND Alt1.product_code = altStuff.ALT1SKU
LEFT JOIN @BUCKET Alt2 ON Alt2.store_code_id = s.store_code_id AND Alt2.Bin_Code in ('STORE', 'VW', 'V') AND Alt2.product_code = altStuff.ALT2SKU
LEFT JOIN @BUCKET Alt3 ON Alt3.store_code_id = s.store_code_id AND Alt3.Bin_Code in ('STORE', 'VW', 'V') AND Alt3.product_code = altStuff.ALT3SKU
LEFT JOIN @BUCKET Alt4 ON Alt4.store_code_id = s.store_code_id AND Alt4.Bin_Code in ('STORE', 'VW', 'V') AND Alt4.product_code = altStuff.ALT4SKU
LEFT JOIN @BUCKET Alt5 ON Alt5.store_code_id = s.store_code_id AND Alt5.Bin_Code in ('STORE', 'VW', 'V') AND Alt5.product_code = altStuff.ALT5SKU
LEFT JOIN @BUCKET Alt6 ON Alt6.store_code_id = s.store_code_id AND Alt6.Bin_Code in ('STORE', 'VW', 'V') AND Alt6.product_code = altStuff.ALT6SKU
CROSS JOIN pp_Channel c  
CROSS JOIN altStuff           
WHERE (((l.region IS NOT NULL) AND (l.region <> '099')) OR (l.store = '0010'))
    AND s.store_code <> '0012'
    AND (l.date_opened <= GETDATE())
    AND ((l.date_closed IS NULL) OR (l.date_closed > GETDATE()))    
    AND c.channel_description = 'TEST'  
GROUP BY l.region, l.region_description, s.store_code, s.name, s.city, p.province_code, s.telephone
, b.store_code, b.product_code, b.product_id, c.Channel_Index
```

Comment: Hogan, Much appreciate your effort in helping me with this. I've pasted my full code here http://pastebin.com/erJyjB2z Looking at that would give you a much better picture on what I'm trying to do. @ALT may have multiple rows but in my left joins, I'm selecting by a row number so it should return just one. I will review your code above now. Thanks.

Comment: @Eclipse -- please spend at least as much time reading my code and understanding it as I spent writing it.  **I DID RESTRICT BY ROW NUMBER** This is exactly WHY I said if it does not return one row you have a problem.  The symptom you describe is that there is more than one row.

Comment: Hogan, I see what you're doing with the AltStuff. However, I do get an error at this line   FROM ALT ALT1
  CROSS JOIN ALT ALT1 . I commented those two lines and got no rows. Also, the bin_qty_stocks column is not in this table. Please let me know if you had the chance to look at what I pasted here http://pastebin.com/erJyjB2z You'll see the data in those two temp tables.

Comment: Yes the first cross join should be removed (I've done so.) your examples above look wrong.  EG you say `FROM ALT ALT1` I have `FROM @ALT ALT1`

Comment: I'm not going to go to a pastebin and look at more code of yours -- apply what I've shown you so far first.  Unless you hire me as a consultant -- contact me via stackoverflow's jobs feature -- but I doubt you can afford me.

Comment: I appreciate that you have provided a solution but if you see the whole picture it will make much more sense on what I'm looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @Eclipse -- I'm going to say this very clearly -- I'm not interested in helping you any more unless you pay me.

Comment: ah. got it. I hope someone else will chime in to solve this question. Thanks for your time.